# Radiant CMS - undefined method `camelize' for "instance":String

Tags: ruby, rubygems, freebsd, radiant

I installed radiant on a freebsd 8 box. When I launch it I get the following error :
"undefined method `camelize' for "instance":String"

This is what I have :

```
[root@freebsd-esxi ~]# ruby --version 
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-freebsd8]

[root@freebsd-esxi ~]# gem --version
1.6.2

[root@freebsd-esxi ~]# gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
activerecord (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
arel (2.0.9)
builder (2.1.2)
i18n (0.5.0)
rack (1.1.2)
radiant (0.9.1) 
rake (0.8.7)
RedCloth (4.2.7)
sources (0.0.2)
tzinfo (0.3.25)
will_paginate (2.3.15)

[root@freebsd-esxi ~]# radiant --help
undefined method `camelize' for "instance":String
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Someone else had almost the same problem and fixed it by rebuilding their Ruby iconv library:

```
$ cd /usr/ports/converters/ruby-iconv
$ make install clean
```

I'm not a FreeBSD guru so this may or may not work for you.